# Drawing 2D HUD over 3D OpenGL sence with SDL

Tags: opengl, 3d, 2d, sdl-2, hud

I'm trying to draw a 2D HUD over a 3D Scene and therefor I'm useing the opengl rendering set up on SDL. 
So the question is :
Is it possible to Draw 2D things with SDL over the 3D scene or do I need to draw them with opengl?
Because I've experienced that if I create a SDL renderer the OpenGL scene will disappear and be overdrawn by the SDL renderer.

Comment: I would just do it in OpenGL using an orthographic projection, pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, OpenGL has functions for drawing 2D elements. You could render the 3D to a texture and then render 2D over it. If you must use SDL, you'll need a method to copy an OpenGL texture to an SDL surface/texture.

Comment: Thanks for that idea, but I decided to do it like Zammalad said. I'm drawing the stuff with OpenGL ;)